# CSS - Text Slider

Tags: css

newbie here so go easy on me...

I'm implemented a slider to display multiple text testimonials.

I used the code from here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/tu1e6uq5 (slideshow of testimonials)

.. and have implemented it here: http://www.yourtelemarketing.co.uk/testimonial.html

However, I have just discovered the text slider doesn't seem to work in Chrome or Firefox, (all fine in IE11)

Any ideas on how to fix?
Many thanks.

(Just to clarify - I'm taking about the text testimonials not sliding, not the banner/hero images, which work just fine.)

Comment: HTML/CSS & JS please.

Comment: Slideshow looks fine to me in Chrome

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm taking about the testimonials not sliding, not the banner/hero images.

Comment: works fine too in FF, why negative value for delay ?

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work in my FF though. You are looking at the testimonial text (to right of the red cloud)? Negative delay apparently needed to pause the slider on mouse-hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect your webpage in chrome console and look at styles. You'll notice that the animation properties are crossed. I think you need to define them by prefixing "-webkit-" ,"-moz-", etc depending upon the browsers. Similar to this:

```
-webkit-animation: tsl-fade-in-out 25s infinite;
-moz-animation: tsl-fade-in-out 25s infinite;
-ms-animation: tsl-fade-in-out 25s infinite;
-o-animation: tsl-fade-in-out 25s infinite;
animation: tsl-fade-in-out 25s infinite;
```

and so on for other animation property. 
Similarly you need to add

```
@-moz-keyframes tsl-fade-in-out{
  ...
}

@-webkit-keyframes tsl-fade-in-out{
  ...
}
```

alongwith the keyframes.
Try this. It might solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking - have implemented (as far as I can see where to do so..), doesn't seem to have helped though :-(

Comment: You missed the animation-delay property. You need to change that also